# Clang LLVM disable va_arg expansion

Tags: c++, c, clang, llvm-ir

I am writing an llvm tool that uses the generated llvm IR bit code. and for va_arg clang expands it into

```
getelementptr instruction
```

with fixed positions and memory layout

instead of using

```
va_arg instruction
```

is there any compiler flag to disable this expansion ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, no, because variable argument handling is platform-specific.

Moreover, I tried to use VA instructions from LLVM IR and sometimes it was resulting in wrong machine code. There are a lot of intricacies there, and that's why IR VA instructions are going to be deprecated.

Comment: mg tool aims to convert the generated bitcode to msil .net, and I will provide custom implementaion for va_arg .. but I need to disable va_arg expansion in clang